# two vector<string> concatenation

Tags: c++, string, vector, concatenation

I have two vectors , like this:

```
A ={"Sam", "Jordan", "Mike"}
B ={"Smith", "Lancaster", "Horgen"}
```

After Concatenation, They should look like this:

```
A ={"SamSmith", "JordanLancaster", "MikeHorgen"}
```

Basically, you combine first and last names. 
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < A.size() && i < B.size(); ++i)
   A[i] += B[i];
```

Now the `A` vector contains the required output.

Comment: you have 2 for loops, I tried, and it's like this: SamSmith, SamLancaster, SamHorgen, JordanSmith, JordanLancaster, JordanHorgen, MikeSmith, MikeLancaster, MikeHorgen

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::transform` ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1a756940e3e1b9f)):

```
std::transform(
    begin(A), end(A), begin(B), begin(A), 
    [](const auto& s1, const auto& s2) { return s1 + s2; }
);
```

Comment: "auto is not allowed here", I don't know what that means

Comment: @JY078 Your compiler doesn't support generic lambdas. Specify the parameter types explicitly (e.g. `std::string`)

Comment: @JY078, Yes, as said, that was just for convenience and works in C++14.

Answer (score 0):

It could done easily by iterating over two vectors and `concatenating` strings in each step and assigning result back into `A`,

```
 typedef vector<string>::iterator VIter;

    for(VIter it1=A.begin(), it2=B.begin(); it1 != A.end(), it2 != B.end(); ++it1, ++it2)
    {
            *it1 = *it1 +*it2;
    }
```